# Linking a javascript file to my current Javascript file

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am currently developing a web application where we are using the Model View Controller method for organizing our information and code. In our case we are combining the View and Controller into one Javascript file and the Model is separate.

My question comes here. I've got prototype objects in my model, but I want to instantiate instances of these objects in my viewcontroller Javascript file. How do I get them talking to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to achieve that. Today, the simplest one would be:

```
<script src='model.js'></script>
<script src='view-controller.js'></script>
```

So, since your model.js will be loaded first, you can use it inside the view/controller.

---

Another way is by using modules. The most used today is [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). E.g:

```
require(['model'], function(model) {
  // This function is called when model.js is loaded.
  // If model.js calls define(), then this function is not fired until
  // model's dependencies have loaded, and the model argument will hold
  // the module value for model.js.
});
```

ECMAScript 6 (the next version of Javascript), will have [native modules](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/wiki/Brief-Overview-of-ES6-Module-syntax), so you'll be able to do:

```
import * as model from './model'

var x = model.variable; // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look into using Browserify if you are familiar with Node and RequireJS as you an also use NPM modules in the front-end. 
http://browserify.org/

Browserify allows you to export your JS code from one file and require it in another (simplified idea).

file 1: myfunc.js

```
var myFunc = function(){

    console.log("I'm an exported function that's in another file");
};

module.exports = myFunc;
```

file 2: app.js

```
var myFunc = require('./myfunc.js');
myFunc(): // logs "I'm an exported function that's in another file"
```